# Google Play Review API not returning all results

Tags: android, api, google-play-services, review, google-play-developer-api

I am working with https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews/list API to get all reviews of an app.

But even after following all the instructions in the documentation like creating Auth API, using it to validating app account I am only getting latest 2 reviews.

Can anyone please help.

**EDIT:**

Access token received in usual way by calling google oauth login method. then calling this URL in get method to receive reviews.

https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/your_package_name/reviews?
access_token=your_auth_token

Comment: It would be useful if you'd share your code that calls the API.

Comment: Hello @irundaia information updated. Please have a look.

Comment: Make sure that you provided the [access_token](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization) properly. Sometimes, the error is having wrong token copied. If this is not the case, try getting new token. Be noted that each access token is only valid for a short time. Once the current access token expires, the server will need to use the refresh token to get a new one. You can check this [sample code](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidpublisher/v2/python/latest/androidpublisher_v2.reviews.html).

Comment: @ronns can you tell me how you get that access token ..i tried more i didnt get that.Can you pls tell

Comment: @ronns is the above code still working. I was trying to create a similar code but getting authentication error during check in

com.akdeniz.googleplaycrawler.GooglePlayException: Error=BadAuthentication
 at com.akdeniz.googleplaycrawler.GooglePlayAPI.executeHttpRequest(GooglePlayAPI.java:522)
 at com.akdeniz.googleplaycrawler.GooglePlayAPI.executePost(GooglePlayAPI.java:482)
 at com.akdeniz.googleplaycrawler.GooglePlayAPI.executePost(GooglePlayAPI.java:462)
 at com.akdeniz.googleplaycrawler.GooglePlayAPI.loginAC2DM(GooglePlayAPI.java:180)

Answer (score 4):

Only reviews from last 2 weeks are displayed.

Comment: I was trying to create a similar code but getting authentication error during check in 

com.akdeniz.googleplaycrawler.GooglePlayException: Error=BadAuthentication at com.akdeniz.googleplaycrawler.GooglePlayAPI.executeHttpRequest(GooglePlayAPI.java:522) at com.akdeniz.googleplaycrawler.GooglePlayAPI.executePost(GooglePlayAPI.java:482) at com.akdeniz.googleplaycrawler.GooglePlayAPI.executePost(GooglePlayAPI.java:462) at com.akdeniz.googleplaycrawler.GooglePlayAPI.loginAC2DM(GooglePlayAPI.java:180)
<BR><BR>
Any suggestion greatly appreciated